# Excel 2010 VBA: Using Relative references across multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to design a macro to simplify the update process for my company's order tracking, and I'm struggling with relative references. I'm using Excel 2010.

what I need the macro to do: Find a given part number on one workbook, and use the row number of to update formulas in a a second workbook.

In more detail:

Where |Y|= column letter of original spreadsheet, |X|= row number of original spreadsheet, and |X^|=Row number of ‘All Inventory.xls’

There are 4 separate spreadsheets I would need to run the macro from (It’d be a lot easier if I could have the 4 as separate pages on one spreadsheet, but unfortunately, my boss is 60 and is a bit fuzzy on how excel works.)

The spreadsheet ‘All Inventory.xls’ is not in table form, and I can’t convert it to one. (the guy who runs inventory is very fuzzy on how spreadsheets work, approximately five years from retirement, and about as friendly as a snapping turtle.)

When run from cell |Y||X| in a table:

1. Copy content of the cell in table column ‘Part #’ in the same row – structured reference [@[Part #]]|X|
2. Paste content of cell ‘[@[Part #]]|X|’ into Find/Replace
3. Switch to spreadsheet ‘All Inventory.xls’
4. Hit ‘find next’ – will land on cell C|X^|
5. switch back to original spreadsheet
6. return to original cell |Y||X|
7. type “=’[All Inventory.xls]Sheet1’!$E$|X^|”
8. go to cell |Y+1||X|
9. type “=’[All Inventory.xls]Sheet1’!$G$|X^|”
10. go to cell [Y][X+1]
11. End macro

I've tried recording this directly, while using relative references. Excel didn't like that. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: a picture and a [mcve] of a specific problem are worth more than anything in the post above. please edit according the [ask] guidelines.

Comment: 2 things.. First, what have you tried so far? Second, loving the explanation of why you cannot change format :D